# Multiplication sign in TeXForm?

Tags: output-formatting, latex

How do I get Mathematica to produce TeX output that does not omit the
multiplication signs?

For example, this expression:

```
(z03*z14*z32 + z01*z12*z43 + z14*(z01 + z03 + z12 + z32)*z43)
```

displays in Mathematica as:

```
(z14 z43 (z01+z03+z12+z32)+z01 z12 z43+z03 z14 z32)
```

And the output of TeXForm looks like this:

```
(z14 z43 (z01 + z03 + z12 + z32) + z01 z12 z43 + z03 z14 z32) // TeXForm
```

> $
> \text{z14} \text{z43} (\text{z01}+\text{z03}+\text{z12}+\text{z32})+\text{z01} \text{z12}
>    \text{z43}+\text{z03} \text{z14} \text{z32}$

which is really hard to read because the spaces get ignored.

How do I get TeXForm to produce this instead?:
$$
\text{z14}\times\text{z43}\times(\text{z01}+\text{z03}+\text{z12}+\text{z32})+\text{z01}\times\text{z12}\times\text{z43}+\text{z03}\times\text{z14}\times\text{z32}
$$

Even better would be:

$$
\text{z14}.\text{z43}.(\text{z01}+\text{z03}+\text{z12}+\text{z32})+\text{z01}.\text{z12}.\text{z43}+\text{z03}.\text{z14}.\text{z32}
$$

Worse come to worse, I could even settle for something like this:
$$
\text{z14}\;\text{z43}\;(\text{z01}+\text{z03}+\text{z12}+\text{z32})+\text{z01}\;\text{z12}\;\text{z43}+\text{z03}\;\text{z14}\;\text{z32}
$$

Comment: Use a string and `\[Times]` instead of `*` for multiplication?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a [*very robust (!!)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarcasm) method

```
expr = (z14 z43 (z01 + z03 + z12 + z32) + z01 z12 z43 + z03 z14 z32);
StringReplace[ToString[expr, TeXForm], " " :> "\\times"]
```

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy as plain text results in

$$\text{z14}\times\text{z43}\times(\text{z01}+\text{z03}+\text{z12}+\text{z32})+\text{z01}\times\text{z12}\times\text{z43}+\text{z03}\times\text{z14}\times\text{z32}$$

### Edit

The above approach might serve you well in the simple setting the OP is representing, in general, this method is very likely to break, because it relies on that a multiplication is converted into a single space in `TeXForm`.

As questions in our [latex tag](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex)  suggest, there are several problems and subtilities with `TeXForm` and a general and always working answer can hardly be given at this point without further information.

Comment: This works, thanks

Comment: well, now that I am starting to use your trick more, I find that it is not _that_ robust. It works most of the time, but fails when there is a greek letter in the expression: for some reason, Mathematica adds a space after greek letters in the TeXForm output, and that gets caught as a mutltiply by your strignreplace technique. Darn.

Comment: @blondiepassesby I thought you were aware that the italic *very robust* in my answer was more a warning sign than a statement?! I was really meant ironically, because I was afraid that it might not work in certain cases.

Comment: Hmm. Not entirely sure that irony is that helpful or even encouraged on stackexchange answers, especially the kind that may or may not be picked by  readers of your answers. I certainly didn't read it as such and accepted your answer at face value. In future, I'd recommend being as explicit as possible.

Comment: @blondiepassesby First, I'm sorry that you haven't been able to pick up that it meant *use it with caution*. I thought it was obvious, that a string-replacement in the final texform will not work in all possible circumstances. You are free to unaccept my answer. But before you *recommend* something, I want you to recall that everyone answering here is very likely doing it in his free time, just for fun. If you want a general solution, free of irony, you just have to pay money and you'll get a totally serious answer/solution.

Answer (score 5):

We want cross? Let's use `Cross`!

```
expr /. Times -> Cross // TeXForm
```

$
\text{z14}\times (\text{z01}+\text{z03}+\text{z12}+\text{z32})\times
   \text{z43}+\text{z01}\times \text{z12}\times
   \text{z43}+\text{z03}\times \text{z14}\times \text{z32}
$

Comment: Or, if the OP prefers, 'expr /. Times -> Dot // TeXForm'

Answer (score 3):

`Row` appears to work:

```
expr = (z03*z14*z32 + z01*z12*z43 + z14*(z01 + z03 + z12 + z32)*z43);
expr /. Times :> (Row[{##}, "\[Times]"] &) // TeXForm
```

Copying as plain text as halirutan did and wrapping in `$` symbols:

$\text{z14}\times \text{z01}+\text{z03}+\text{z12}+\text{z32}\times \text{z43}+\text{z01}\times \text{z12}\times
   \text{z43}+\text{z03}\times \text{z14}\times \text{z32}$

---

- **Note:** This code fails in recent versions due to a bug: [Incompatibility of Row and TeXForm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55363/121).
  kguler discovered that the bug may be circumvented by setting:

  ```
  BoxForm`$UseTemplateSlotSequenceForRow = False;
  ```

Comment: Hmm, does this really work for you? Here, I get [this output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6ozoR.png).

Comment: @halirutan In version 7, yes, it does.  I already voted for your answer.  (Does a space *always* represent multiplication in TeX?)

Answer (score 2):

TeXForm works by creating [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) boxes, and then converting those boxes into a TeX string. This means there are two methods to change the [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) format of an expression:

1. Change the [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) output
2. Change the conversion code that converts [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) boxes into TeX.

I like changing the [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) output instead of changing the conversion code, because boxes don't carry context. There may be multiple expressions that produce similar boxes, and if you try to write conversion code after the expression has been turned into boxes you may be affecting expressions that you don't want to modify. It's a little bit like trying to repair a car after an accident vs preventing the accident in the first place.

So, the first step is to figure out how to change the [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) of products. Without going into details, this is actually difficult to do, because a variety of different expressions will produce expression that look like space separated terms. So, rather than try to add formatting rules for all of these different expressions, it is much simpler to look for the signature of a product of terms, which is:

```
RowBox[{a, " ", b, " ", c, ..}]
```

and then replace all the spaces with the symbol of your choice (in fact, [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) already does something like this when it tries to reorder products into a more "TraditionalForm" like order).

Therefore, we want to add a [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) formatting rule that post-processes the [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) boxes after all other formatting has take place. The way I will implement this is to add a rule that gets fired before any other formatting has occurred. This rule will create the normal [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) boxes, and then convert any products into "$\times$" separated products. For this purpose, it will be convenient to make use of my [`Initial`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153885/45431) wrapper, which I repeat here for convenience:

```
Initial /: Verbatim[TagSetDelayed][Initial[sym_], lhs_, rhs_] := With[
    {
    new=Block[{sym},
        TagSetDelayed[sym,lhs,rhs];
        First @ Language`ExtendedDefinition[sym]
    ],
    protect=Unprotect[sym]
    },

    sym;
    Quiet@MakeBoxes[sym[],TraditionalForm];

    Unprotect[sym];
    Replace[
        new,
        Rule[values_,n:Except[{}]] :> (
            values[sym] = DeleteDuplicates @ Join[n, values[sym]]
        ),
        {2}
    ];
    Protect@protect;
]
```

Using the `Initial` wrapper, the following [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes) rule will fire before all others:

```
Initial[TraditionalForm] /: MakeBoxes[e_, TraditionalForm] /; TrueQ@$TeX := Block[{$TeX = False},
    ReplaceAll[
        MakeBoxes[e, TraditionalForm],
        RowBox[b_?productQ] :> RuleCondition @ Replace[RowBox[b], " "->"\[Times]", {2}]
    ]
]
productQ[b_] := Length[b]>1 && MatchQ[b[[2 ;; -2 ;; 2]], {" "..}]
```

Let's see this in action:

```
$TeX = False;
x+2y //TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Versus:

```
$TeX = True;
x+2y //TraditionalForm
```

[image]

All that remains is to modify the [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) code to block `$TeX` to [`True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/True) when creating the [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) boxes. This can again be done using the `Initial` wrapper:

```
Initial[Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX] /: 
    Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX[e__] /; !TrueQ@$TeX := Block[
        {$TeX = True},
        Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX[e]
    ]
```

Let's take a look at an example:

```
x+2y //TeXForm
```

> $x+2\times y$

Perfect. For your more complicated example:

```
(z03*z14*z32 + z01*z12*z43 + z14*(z01 + z03 + z12 + z32)*z43) //TeXForm
```

> $\text{z14}\times \text{z43}\times
>    (\text{z01}+\text{z03}+\text{z12}+\text{z32})+\text{z01}\times \text{z12}\times
>    \text{z43}+\text{z03}\times \text{z14}\times \text{z32}$

Here is the above code in one block:

```
Initial /: Verbatim[TagSetDelayed][Initial[sym_], lhs_, rhs_] := With[
    {
    new=Block[{sym},
        TagSetDelayed[sym,lhs,rhs];
        First @ Language`ExtendedDefinition[sym]
    ],
    protect=Unprotect[sym]
    },

    sym;
    Quiet@MakeBoxes[sym[],TraditionalForm];

    Unprotect[sym];
    Replace[
        new,
        Rule[values_,n:Except[{}]] :> (
            values[sym] = DeleteDuplicates @ Join[n, values[sym]]
        ),
        {2}
    ];
    Protect@protect;
]

Initial[TraditionalForm] /: MakeBoxes[e_, TraditionalForm] /; TrueQ@$TeX := Block[{$TeX = False},
    ReplaceAll[
        MakeBoxes[e, TraditionalForm],
        RowBox[b_?productQ] :> RuleCondition @ Replace[RowBox[b], " "->"\[Times]", {2}]
    ]
]
productQ[b_] := Length[b]>1 && MatchQ[b[[2 ;; -2 ;; 2]], {" "..}]

Initial[Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX] /: 
    Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX[e__] /; !TrueQ@$TeX := Block[
        {$TeX = True},
        Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX[e]
    ]
```