# HoldForm does not Hold Form for fractions sometimes

Tags: formatting, hold, latex, conversion

I'm facing a strange behavior of `HoldForm`.

I need to display `1/2*3/4` in LaTeX like this :
$$ \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{3}{4} $$

So I use Mathematica : `1/2* 3/4 // HoldForm // TeXForm`
BUT I get 
$$ \frac{3}{2\ 4} $$

First the writing `2 space 4` is ambigous and second it does not hold form at all :(

Can you help me ?
Thank you ! (happy Holidays)

**EDIT : I would need an automatic transformation of any input to correct TeX or an automatic correction of any output to correct TeX.**

Comment: Related: [Multiplication sign in TeXForm?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39061/18476)

Comment: Another way: HoldForm[Divide[1, 2]  Divide[3, 4]] // TeXForm

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `HoldForm` applied to each fraction to keep the fractions from combining.

```
HoldForm[1/2] HoldForm[3/4]
```

to produce $$ \frac{1}{2} \frac{3}{4} $$

or

```
HoldForm[(1/2) (3/4)]
```

to produce $$ \frac{3}{2 \times 4} $$

Using `TeXForm` produces the desired LaTex code.

```
(HoldForm[1/2] HoldForm[3/4]) // TeXForm
(* \frac{1}{2} \frac{3}{4} *)
```

**Addendum**

Simpler is

```
Infix[f[1/2, 3/4], "\[Times]"] // TeXForm
(* \frac{1}{2}\times \frac{3}{4} *)
```

which also provides the times sign.  $$\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{3}{4}$$

**Second Addendum**

```
z1 z2 /. Times -> Cross /. {z1 -> 1/2, z2 -> 3/4} // TeXForm
```

also produces the desired output.  (This is based on the third Answer to [39061](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39061/multiplication-sign-in-texform).)

Comment: How can I automatically apply this to my input `1/2*3/4` ?

Comment: @Crypto, that depends on the form of your input.  If you literally want to change `1/2*3/4` to the form in  my last equation, doing so is easy.  However, I would guess that you want to do something more complicated.  Please give an actual example, if possible, if your input.

Comment: I mean, I am looking for a way to get the more accurate TeX translation of my input.

I can make any transformation before or after, apply any Mathematica function or any post processing. Currently, I get the TeX Output and add a \times where there is a space. So the current output is $$\frac{3}{2 \times 4} $$ I would like any other transformation to be more accurate. How to convert HoldForm[1/2*3/4] to HoldForm[1/2] HoldForm[3/4] in an aotomated way for example.

Comment: @Crypto, please provide example, so I know what you have in mind.  For instance, is it just the product of two fractions?

Comment: I have seen this kind of behaviour only with fractions (but maybe there are others). So first, I would need a trick to bypass this fraction behaviour automatically. (Maybe there is nothing simple)

Comment: @Crypto, there are many ways to address this issue, depending on how the fractions appear in your input.  For instance, if your input contains, for instance, `z1 z2`, which you later replace by fractions, then the second addendum (which I shall add in a few minutes) works well, I believe.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior you observe is due to the formatting rules associated with `Times`.  Please start by reading my answer here: [Returning an unevaluated expression with values substituted in](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7880/121).  We can apply a similar technique here though the result is not quite as desired if we merely block `Times` during Box creation.  We get:

> $\left(1*\frac{1}{2}\right)*\left(3*\frac{1}{4}\right)$

This form is due to the internal format of `1/2` and `3/4`:

```
Hold[1/2, 3/4] // FullForm
```

> ```
> Hold[Times[1, Power[2, -1]], Times[3, Power[4, -1]]]
> ```

One way to handle this is to post-process the Box form yield the format we desire:

```
SetAttributes[hf, HoldAll]

MakeBoxes[hf[args__], fmt_] := 
 Block[{Times}, MakeBoxes[HoldForm[args], fmt]] /. 
  RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{n_, "*", FractionBox["1", d_]}], ")"}] :> FractionBox[n, d]
```

Now using `hf` in place of `HoldForm`:

```
hf[1/2*3/4] // TeXForm
```

> ```
> \frac{1}{2}*\frac{3}{4}
> ```

Formatted:

> $\frac{1}{2}*\frac{3}{4}$

Comment: Rather very complicated oO, but it could be an option ! I need an automated method to deal with MM input or TeX output in order to convert it into correct TeX.

Comment: @Crypto does using `hf` in place of `HoldForm` not work for you?  If it fails please give me an example so that I can try to improve either my code or my recommendation.

Comment: Your function seems to correct one type problem with fraction. But I am more looking for something able to display TeX in the exact form I write them. Probably MM is not the right tool to use. I am disapointed.

Comment: @Crypto please see the second answer I just added.  If again this doesn't work for you please give an example where it fails.

Answer (score 3):

I am posting a second answer because I am now taking a very different interpretation of your problem.  In a comment below my first answer you state:

> Your function seems to correct one type problem with fraction. But I am more looking for something able to display TeX in the exact form I write them. Probably MM is not the right tool to use. I am disapointed.

I assumed that you were looking for TeX conversion of arbitrary expressions generated by (evaluation in) *Mathematica* but if instead you simply want TeX for expressions in "the exact form I write them" you may be able to use Strings, e.g.:

[image]

The string was created using [standard input methods](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EnteringTwoDimensionalInput.html).  `\[Times]` was entered with <kbd>Esc</kbd>`*`<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Here is the input in copyable form:

```
"\!\(\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(2\)]\)\[Times]\!\(\*FractionBox[\(3\), \(4\)]\)" // TeXForm
```

And the output formatted by MathJax:

$\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{3}{4}$

Critically this method avoids *interpretation* of your raw input into e.g. `Times` and `Power`, thereby bypassing those "pretty printing" rules that were changing your expression in an unwanted way.

Comment: Thank You for this second method.

Answer (score 2):

This unexpected behaviour of HoldForm and Hold seems to be due to the function MakeExpression and not a bug in HoldForm or Hold.

Having entered

```
Hold[1/2 3/4]
```

the frontend sends the command

```
MakeExpression[BoxData[RowBox[{"Hold","[",RowBox[{RowBox[{"1","/","2"}],
  RowBox[{"3","/","4"}]}],"]"}]],StandardForm]
```

to the kernel for further evaluation. The essential part is

```
MakeExpression[BoxData[RowBox[{RowBox[{"a","/","b"}],
  RowBox[{"c","/","d"}]}]],StandardForm]

(* HoldComplete[(a c)/(b d)] *)
```

So already in MakeExpression the numerators and denominaters are collected to one numerator and denominator, before Hold or HoldForm is used.