# Add better style to a dynamic question

Tags: gui-construction, text, style

I would like to obtain something similar to this:
[image: What I want]

A user, has to answer the question selecting an answer from a `popupmenu` and he can check it.

I wrote that:

```
DynamicModule[{r1,r2},listarisposte={PopupMenu[Dynamic[r1], 
         {"",Sequence @@ RandomSample[{"Sin(60)","Cos(60)"}]}]};
         Row[Flatten[{{Text[Subscript["V","x"]],Text["=v*"], listarisposte,Text["40*1/2=20"]}, 
         Button["Controlla", r2 = (r1 == "Cos(60)")],
         Graphics[{Dynamic[If[r2, Green, Red, Gray]], Rectangle[{0, 0}]},ImageSize -> {20, 20}],
         Dynamic[If[r2, "Giusto!", "Sbagliato, riprova!", ""]]}]]];
```

The output is [image: Output]

but it isn't very well styled.
How can I write `1/2` in the fraction form?

How can I resize the text? I tried with `Style` but it doesn't work.

Comment: See [69655](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69655/5478) and [ref/FontSize](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FontSize.html)

Comment: @Kuba FontSize works well, but HoldForm not.
I modified the previous lines as {Text[Style[Subscript["V","x"],FontSize->30]],Text[Style["=V*   ",FontSize->30]], listarisposte,
             Text[Style["   40*"<>ToString[HoldForm[1/2]]<>"=20   ",FontSize->30]]}
But the result is this http://i66.tinypic.com/15zmazo.png

Comment: You can use `ToString[1/2, TraditionalForm]` or use `HoldForm` with `Row` etc, they don't convert it to strings in the linked question.

Comment: Perfect, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've modified your code a bit for readability. The stylish functions `st` and `st2` define the fonts. The value `i` is identifier of the right answer.

```
st=Style[#,20]&;
st2=Style[#,20,Blue,Bold]&;

DynamicModule[{r1 = "", r2, i = RandomInteger[{1, 2}]},
 listarisposte = 
  PopupMenu[Dynamic[r1], 
   Sort@{If[i == 1, 2, 1] -> st@"Sin(60)", i -> st@"Cos(60)"}];
 Row@{
   st@"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(x\)]\)=v*", listarisposte, 
   st@"40*\!\(\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(2\)]\)=20", Spacer[20],
   Button[st@"Controlla", r2 = (r1 == i)], Spacer[20], 
   Graphics[{Dynamic[If[r2, Green, Red, Gray]], Rectangle[{0, 0}]}, 
    ImageSize -> {20, 20}], Spacer[20],
   Dynamic[If[r2, st2@"Giusto!", st2@"Sbagliato, riprova!", ""]]}]
```

[image]

These complicated constructions with a lot of slashes appear when you need to write formatted text as plain one. In MMA it looks nice.

Actually, the formatting of the fractions and subscripts\superscripts in traditional form can be done in MMA easy just using ctrl+/ instead of / or ctrl+_ (ctrl+^) switch the next symbol to subscript or superscript.