# How to avoid that Mathematica simplifies a ratio?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How to avoid that Mathematica simplifies a ratio?

I have this code (visualizing [Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox)):

```
Manipulate[
 Grid[{{a/at, a/at < b/bt, b/bt}, {c/ct, c/ct < d/dt, d/dt}, {(
    a + c)/(at + ct), (a + c)/(at + ct) < (b + d)/(bt + dt), (b + d)/(
    bt + dt)}}, Frame -> All], {{a, 3}, 1, 100, 1}, {{at, 8}, 1, 100, 
  1}, {{b, 16}, 1, 100, 1}, {{bt, 32}, 1, 100, 1}, {{c, 24}, 1, 100, 
  1}, {{ct, 32}, 1, 100, 1}, {{d, 7}, 1, 100, 1}, {{dt, 8}, 1, 100, 
  1}]
```

The problem is that Mathematica simplifies 8/8 to 1 (for example), but I want it to show 8/8. How is this done?

Comment: see: [69655](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69655/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Thanks! But should I apply HoldForm to each expression in the list seperately?

Comment: @Kuba HoldForm doesn't seem to work, it gives: \!\(
TagBox[
FractionBox["FE`a$$178", "FE`at$$178"],
HoldForm]\)

Comment: It works how it is supposed to work but you can't just wrap everything with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
With[
    {range = Sequence[1, 100, 1]}
  , Manipulate[
        Grid[
            {Fraction[#, #2], #/#2 < #3/#4, Fraction[##3]
            } & @@@ {
                {a, at, b, bt}
              , {c, ct, d, dt}
              , {(a + c), (at + ct), (b + d), (bt + dt)}
            }, Frame -> All
        ]
      , {{a, 3}, range}, {{at, 8}, range}, {{b, 16}, range}
      , {{bt, 32}, range}, {{c, 24}, range}, {{ct, 32}, range}
      , {{d, 7}, range}, {{dt, 8}, range}
      , Initialization :> (
            Fraction /: MakeBoxes[Fraction[x_, y_], fmt_
            ] := FractionBox[MakeBoxes[x, fmt], MakeBoxes[y, fmt]]
        )
    ]

 ]
```

Comment: Could use ``Internal`RationalNoReduce`` instead of `Fraction`.

Comment: @CarlWoll maybe, but it doesn't even have usage message. And it is not the same, e.g.: `2 Fraction[1, 2]`

Answer (score 3):

Let me display a slight variation of Kuba's code, while incorporating a modification of [eldo's take](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154874):

```
Manipulate[Column[{disp[a, at, b, bt], disp[c, ct, d, dt],
                   disp[a + c, at + ct, b + d, bt + dt]}],
           {{a, 3}, 1, 100, 1}, {{at, 8}, 1, 100, 1},
           {{b, 16}, 1, 100, 1}, {{bt, 32}, 1, 100, 1},
           {{c, 24}, 1, 100, 1}, {{ct, 32}, 1, 100, 1},
           {{d, 7}, 1, 100, 1}, {{dt, 8}, 1, 100, 1}, 
           Initialization :> (disp[p1_, q1_, p2_, q2_] :=
                              DisplayForm[RowBox[{FractionBox[p1, q1],
                                                  Switch[Sign[p1/q1 - p2/q2],
                                                         -1, "<", 0, "=", 1, ">"],
                                                  FractionBox[p2, q2]}]])]
```

[image: Simpson's paradox demo]