# How to change Boolean into a String, depending on the boolean?

Tags: conditional

I have this code (visualizing [Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox)):

```
Manipulate[
 Grid[{{a/at, a/at < b/bt, b/bt}, {c/ct, c/ct < d/dt, d/dt}, {(
    a + c)/(at + ct), (a + c)/(at + ct) < (b + d)/(bt + dt), (b + d)/(
    bt + dt)}}, Frame -> All], {{a, 3}, 1, 100, 1}, {{at, 8}, 1, 100, 
  1}, {{b, 16}, 1, 100, 1}, {{bt, 32}, 1, 100, 1}, {{c, 24}, 1, 100, 
  1}, {{ct, 32}, 1, 100, 1}, {{d, 7}, 1, 100, 1}, {{dt, 8}, 1, 100, 
  1}]
```

Instead of "True" and "False" I would like it to show ">" or "<". How could I create that?

Comment: What about `If`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Manipulate[
   Grid[{{a/at, a/at < b/bt, b/bt}, {c/ct, c/ct < d/dt, 
      d/dt}, {(a + c)/(at + ct), (a + c)/(at + ct) < (b + d)/(bt + dt), 
       (b + d)/(bt + dt)}} /.
          {True :> ">", False :> "<"}, Frame -> All],
            {{a, 3}, 1, 100, 1}, {{at, 8}, 1, 100, 1}, {{b, 16}, 1, 100, 
            1}, {{bt, 32}, 1, 100, 1}, {{c, 24}, 1, 100, 1}, {{ct, 32}, 1, 100, 
            1}, {{d, 7}, 1, 100, 1}, {{dt, 8}, 1, 100, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Any particular reason for `:>`?

Comment: No, just a habit