# HoldForm: Display exactly as entered?

Tags: evaluation, output-formatting, hold, display

Sometimes, Mathematica's internal representation of expressions can give somewhat surprising results. Specifically, I noticed this when I tried to preserve products of fractions for display.

E.g. the following example as in "[HoldForm does not Hold Form for fractions sometimes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69655/holdform-does-not-hold-form-for-fractions-sometimes)":

[image]

i.e. it isn't easily possible to preserve the output fractions as they are written. This is actually surprising though, because Mathematica internally preserves the "product of two fractions" form:

```
In[1]:=  HoldForm[1/x 1/y]  // InputForm
Out[1]=  HoldForm[(1/x)*(1/y)]

In[2]:=  HoldForm[1/x 1/y]  // FullForm
Out[2]=  HoldForm[Times[Times[1,Power[x,-1]],Times[1,Power[y,-1]]]]
```

Is there some way to get Mathematica to display such forms as actual product of fractions in any of the formatted output forms, *without* manually adding holdform constructs?

Comment: As to the final question, why not just convert input cell to the output once you are done with the input that should not be modified anyway?

Comment: Strongly related: [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5617685/590388), [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6534071/590388).

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
MakeBoxes[Times[a_, b_], StandardForm] := RowBox[{MakeBoxes@a, MakeBoxes@b}]
1/x 1/y 1/z
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Btw, one could argue that `1/x` should be kept in that exact form too, that is no fraction box in input, no fraction box in output.

Comment: @kuba Oh I forgot about that, now I've turned to `MakeBoxes` in all places, thanks for pointing out. As to "no fraction box in input, no fraction box in output" part, I think OP's goal is just obtaining an output consistent with the `FullForm` of the expression, so I'd like to stop here. (I admit that's a harder and interesting question though. Perhaps a new question like "Can I make the display of expression changeless at all?" should be asked? )

Comment: Useful for my usecase, as it controls exactly what is displayed how. I suppose nothing more catch-all than this is doable. @xzczd I'd also prefer if it were possible to keep "1/x" vs the 2-dimensional form separate, but I don't think that this distinction is even kept in the internal representation.

Comment: @kdb Yeah, if $1/x$ and $\frac{1}{x}$ needs to be distincted, I'm afraid something as shown in Kuba's answer is necessary. I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: (+1) An extended version of this approach can be found in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/267969/280) answer.

Answer (score 3):

IMO, the only way to be sure is to interfere as soon as possible:

```
$PreRead = Function[boxes
,  boxes /. 
     RowBox[{"RawInput", "[", hf_, "]"}] :> 
     RowBox[{"RawBoxes", "[", ToBoxes[hf], "]"}]
];
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to use [`InString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InString.html):

```
1/x 1/y
ToExpression[InString[-1], StandardForm, RawBoxes]
```

[image: screenshot]